# How can I connect Airflow Cloud Composer to Cloud SQL using Private IP?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

I'm attempting to connect to a Potgres database running in Cloud SQL, and I have enabled Private IP as shown below with the "Default" settings. I have also added the IP addresses of this Cloud SQL instance as connections into the Airflow instance on Google Cloud Composer. Note I have also set up the Cloud Composer instance with private networking, and the same "Default" options as I did on the Cloud SQL instance when setting it to use Private IP.

I can test connect fine in the connections tab, however I can't run any queries since it says I don't have the correct permissions when I attempt a DAG run. Am I connecting in the correct way, or have I missed a step in connecting to a network in this way?

[image: Google Cloud SQL showing default Private IP settings]

Comment: Hello, could you please share the detail of the error, seems more like an IAM issue than a Networking problem.

Comment: Hey Dayvid, the error is "psycopg2.errors.InsufficientPrivilege: permission denied for table user_ids" which is the table I'm attempting to query with this DAG. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just to add to this, I've explicitly made sure the service account I'm using has each of the Cloud SQL permissions, and the Cloud SQL instance allows incoming connections over private IP. The instance is set up with private IP, however even then I still have the same issue.

Comment: That error looks like a permissions problem within your database, not a connection problem.

Comment: You were fully correct, I was provided with the incorrect user details. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved after correcting database permissions, after help from fellow users above